# in virtualenv, pip installing locally from source fails

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to install a library in a `virtualenv` instance with `pip`. The library version I want ([wxPython 3.0.2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/3.0.2.0/))
is not available on PyPi; it is only available for download from SourceForge. Thus, I have the source tarball downloaded on my machine and I am trying to install it in such a way that it will play nicely with `virtualenv`.

(I am on a Windows computer, running Python 2.7.)

I have tried the following:

- doing a direct install: `pip install wxPython-src-3.0.2.0.tar.bz2`
- extracting the files from the tarball to `wxPython-src-3.0.2.0`, then installing from the extracted directory: `pip install wxPython-src-3.0.2.0`
- extracting the files from the tarball, then navigating into the extracted folder to the nested `wxPython` directory, which holds the `setup.py` file, and then installing from there: `pip install wxPython`

The last attempt seems the most promising, but I get the following traceback:

```
Processing \wxpython-src-3.0.2.0\wxpython
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Setuptools must be installed to build an egg

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\__MY_USERNAME__\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-q0pxlt\
```

This is also strange, because it suggests I don't have setuptools even though I can run `pip list` and see version `40.6.3` installed.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My eventual solution was the easy way out: installing my package (wxPython) locally as @phd suggested, and [opting for local package access](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#the-system-site-packages-option) via either `virtualenv --system-site-packages env` or deleting the "no-global-site-packages.txt" file in an existing environment folder.

Not what I expected to do, but it works so no complaints.

Answer (score 2):

Why not install a precompiled version? There are a lot of .exe files at [SF](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/3.0.2.0/). You probably need wxPython3.0-win64-3.0.2.0-py27.exe.

Also take a look at [Christoph Gohlke's collection](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wxpython).

If you still insist on installing from sources please bear in mind that wxPython 3 is so old it predates `pip`. Forget about `pip`.

First, you need to install wxWidgets as wxPython is just a Python wrapper for wxWidgets C++ library. Extract wxPython-src-3.0.2.0.tar.bz2 and follow instructions in wxPython-src-3.0.2.0/docs/msw/install.txt.

After compiling and installing wxWidgets compile wxPython. See wxPython-src-3.0.2.0/wxPython/docs/BUILD.txt.